# Variable is not updating after changing the input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My controller:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.barcode = 111;
    $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
        $scope.barcode = 123123123;
    };

    $scope.scanThis = function() {
        $scope.barcode = 456456456;
    };
}])
```

My view:

```
<form>
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Code?" ng-model="barcode">
        </label>
        {{barcode}}
    </div>
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan!</button>
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="scanThis()">Scan this!</button>
</form>
```

Is as simple as one input and two buttons to set the "barcode" var value.
It works when I load the view, I can click the buttons and the value changes, but as soon as I change the input value the functions stop working....

EDIT 1:
No, I did not forgot to "link" the view to the controller, I have the following code:

```
.state('tab.dash', {
      url: '/dash',
      views: {
        'tab-dash': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
          controller: 'ExampleController'
        }
      }
    })
```

EDIT 2:
If i use:

```
<form ng-controller="ExampleController">
```

It works, as well as if I use "$parent" like this:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Code?" ng-model="$parent.barcode">
```

This means that using the "state" is not working as I expected... It's creating a "local" scope for the input when is modified...

Comment: do you see "111" in the input when you load the view? if not, the ExampleController scope probably isn't the same used by the form elements (ex: if the form is part of a directive)

Comment: It would help greatly if you would create a Plunkr demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is probably not very a good thing to do so I'll just put it here: as a quick fix, you can reference the <input> parent scope by replacing bardcode with $parent.barcode in the html. It should work, but there are better ways to do it - like having a different controller for the form or modifying any directive you may be using...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add ng-controller directive.

```
<form ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Code?" ng-model="barcode">
        </label>
        {{barcode}}
    </div>
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan!</button>
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="scanThis()">Scan this!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But, It works... if I use $parent.barcode on the input it also works... That means that using the "state" is not working as expected....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is related to [not having a dot in your ng-model](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). I can't be 100% sure without a Plunkr to demonstrate the issue, but if I were troubleshooting the problem this would be the first place I would look.

As an aside, the dot in scope problem is why I prefer using [the vm variable and "controller as" syntax](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) recommended by John Papa.